# processing to js not working properly

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I'm very new to processing.js and I'm trying to port a pr-sketch to js. I can't just load the pde, because I have to insert some js-socket.io events afterwards.

So the thing is that the sketch is loading, but just a part of it. 
The sketch is kind of a particle system (Node class), an attractor that is attracting the nodes(Attractor class) and the main sketch(FLIP_IDLE).

It seems like the main ketch is loading but not the classes, but I'm not sure :(
(The port is done with the processing.helper.html)

Here is the original pde code:

```
//Particles count
int nodeCount = 4000;

boolean attOut = false;
boolean rainbow = false;

//Moving path for attractor
float angle = 0.0;
int freqX = 8;
int freqY = 8;
int phi = 90;
int modFreqX = 15;
int modFreqY = 15;

float offsetX;
float offsetY;

float scalar = 450;
float speed = 0.0008;

float myC = 0;

//Radius (1920 x 1080)
int myRadius2 = 541; //

float myColor;
float myColor2;

Node[] myNodes = new Node[nodeCount];
Attractor myAttractor;

void setup(){

  //Center of moving path
  offsetX = width/2;
  offsetY = height/2;


  size(1920,1080); 
  colorMode(HSB,100);
  background(255); 

  //Create particles
  for(int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++){
    myNodes[i] = new Node(width/2, height/2);
    myNodes[i].velocity.x = random(-8,8);
    myNodes[i].velocity.y = random(-8,8);
    myNodes[i].damping = 0.01;
  }

  //Create attractor
   myAttractor = new Attractor(0, 0);
}

void draw(){


  //Moving path
  float x = offsetX + sin(angle*freqX + radians(phi)) * cos(angle * modFreqX) * 500;
  float y = offsetY + sin(angle*freqY) * cos(angle * modFreqY) * 500;

  //float x = offsetX + sin(angle*freqX + radians(phi)) * 500;
  //float y = offsetY + sin(angle*freqY) * 500;
  angle += speed;

  fill(0,10);
  rect(0,0,width,height);

  //Attractor position
  myAttractor.x = x;
  myAttractor.y = y;

  for(int i = 0; i < myNodes.length; i++){

    myAttractor.attract(myNodes[i]);
    myNodes[i].damping = 0.01;

    if(attOut == true){

      myAttractor.ramp = 0.7;
      myAttractor.x = width/2;
      myAttractor.y = height/2;       

       if(myNodes[i].myD >= myRadius2){  

         myNodes[i].velocity.x = 0;
         myNodes[i].velocity.y = 0;     
       }

    }else{
      myAttractor.ramp = 0.99;    
    }

    if(myC > 100)
      myC = 0;

    myC = myC + 0.000002;

    myColor = map(sin(myC),-0.98,0.98,0,82);  
    myColor2 = map(sin(myC),-0.98,0.98,20,30);

    //Update and draw particles
    myNodes[i].Update();
    noStroke();

    if(rainbow == true){
      fill(myColor,100,100);
    }else{
      fill(myColor2,100,100);
    }
    ellipse(myNodes[i].x, myNodes[i].y, 2.5, 2.5);
  }

  //Round screen border
  noFill();
  stroke(40,200,100);
  ellipse(width/2,height/2,1080,1080);
  noStroke(); 
}

/*
  --------UI---------
  1 = IDLE
  2 = ACTIVE
  3 = EVALUATION
*/
void keyPressed(){
  if(key=='1'){
    attOut=false;
    rainbow = false;
    myAttractor.radius = 350;
    myAttractor.strength = 0.4;
    speed = 0.001;

  }else if(key == '2'){
    attOut=false;
    rainbow = true;
    myAttractor.radius = 350;
    myAttractor.strength = 0.7;
    speed = 0.0008;    

  }else if(key == '3'){

    if(myAttractor.strength >= 0)
      myAttractor.strength *= -1;
    attOut=true;
    myAttractor.radius = 600;
  }
}

class Attractor {
  // position
  float x=0, y=0; 

  // radius of impact
  float radius = 400;
  float strength = 0.4;  
  float ramp = 0.99;


  Attractor(float theX, float theY) {
    x = theX;
    y = theY;
  }


  void attract(Node theNode) {
    // calculate distance
    float dx = x - theNode.x;
    float dy = y - theNode.y;
    float d = mag(dx, dy);



    if (d > 0 && d < radius) {
      // calculate force
      float s = d/radius;
      float f = (1 / pow(s, 0.5*ramp) - 1);
      f = strength * f/radius;

      // apply force to node velocity
      theNode.velocity.x += dx * f;
      theNode.velocity.y += dy * f;
    }
  }
}


class Node extends PVector{
  PVector velocity = new PVector();
  float minX = 5, minY = 5, maxX = width-5, maxY = height-5;
  float damping = 0.9;
  PVector v1 = new PVector(width/2, height/2,0);
  float myD;
  int myRadius = 541;


  Node(float theX, float theY){
    x = theX;
    y = theY;

  }

  void Update(){
     x += velocity.x;
     y += velocity.y;

     /*
     PVector baseDelta = velocity.normalize();
     PVector normal = new PVector(-baseDelta.y, baseDelta.x);

     PVector incidence = PVector.mult(velocity, -1);
     incidence.normalize();
     */
      myD = dist(v1,this);

      if(myD >= myRadius){  
         velocity.x = -velocity.x;
         velocity.y = -velocity.y;
      }

      velocity.x *= (1-damping);
      velocity.y *= (1-damping);

    }
}
```

and here is the html file with the js:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Arturs JS</title>
    <script src="processing.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        function whenImGoodAndReady() 
        {
            var mySketch = (function($p) 
            {   
                var Attractor = (function() 
                {
                    function Attractor() 
                    {
                        var $this_1 = this;

                        function $superCstr() {
                            $p.extendClassChain($this_1)
                        }
                        $this_1.x = 0;
                        $this_1.y = 0;
                        $this_1.radius = 400;
                        $this_1.strength = 0.4;
                        $this_1.ramp = 0.99;

                        function attract$1(theNode) {
                            var dx = $this_1.x - theNode.x;
                            var dy = $this_1.y - theNode.y;
                            var d = $p.mag(dx, dy);

                            if (d > 0 && d < $this_1.radius) {
                                var s = d / $this_1.radius;
                                var f = (1 / $p.pow(s, 0.5 * $this_1.ramp) - 1);
                                f = $this_1.strength * f / $this_1.radius;

                                theNode.velocity.x += dx * f;
                                theNode.velocity.y += dy * f;
                            }
                        }
                        $p.addMethod($this_1, 'attract', attract$1, false);

                        function $constr_2(theX, theY) {
                            $superCstr();

                            $this_1.x = theX;
                            $this_1.y = theY;
                        }

                        function $constr() {
                            if (arguments.length === 2) {
                                $constr_2.apply($this_1, arguments);
                            } else $superCstr();
                        }
                        $constr.apply(null, arguments);
                    }
                    return Attractor;
                })();

                $p.Attractor = Attractor;

                var Node = (function() {
                    function Node() {
                        var $this_1 = this;
                        var $super = {
                            $upcast: $this_1
                        };

                        function $superCstr() {
                            $p.PVector.apply($super, arguments);
                            if (! ('$self' in $super)) $p.extendClassChain($super)
                        }
                        $this_1.velocity = new $p.PVector();
                        $this_1.minX = 5;
                        $this_1.minY = 5;
                        $this_1.maxX = $p.width - 5;
                        $this_1.maxY = $p.height - 5;
                        $this_1.damping = 0.9;
                        $this_1.v1 = new $p.PVector($p.width / 2, $p.height / 2, 0);
                        $this_1.myD = 0;
                        $this_1.myRadius = 541;

                        function Update$0() {
                            x += $this_1.velocity.x;
                            y += $this_1.velocity.y;

                            $this_1.myD = $p.dist($this_1.v1, $this_1.$self);

                            if ($this_1.myD >= $this_1.myRadius) {
                                $this_1.velocity.x = -$this_1.velocity.x;
                                $this_1.velocity.y = -$this_1.velocity.y;
                            }

                            $this_1.velocity.x *= (1 - $this_1.damping);
                            $this_1.velocity.y *= (1 - $this_1.damping);
                        }
                        $p.addMethod($this_1, 'Update', Update$0, false);

                        function $constr_2(theX, theY) {
                            $superCstr();

                            x = theX;
                            y = theY;
                        }

                        function $constr() {
                            if (arguments.length === 2) {
                                $constr_2.apply($this_1, arguments);
                            } else $superCstr();
                        }
                        $constr.apply(null, arguments);
                    }
                    Node.$base = $p.PVector;
                    return Node;
                })();


                $p.Node = Node;

                var nodeCount = 4000;

                var attOut = false;
                var rainbow = false;

                var angle = 0.0;
                var freqX = 8;
                var freqY = 8;
                var phi = 90;
                var modFreqX = 15;
                var modFreqY = 15;

                var offsetX = 0;
                var offsetY = 0;

                var scalar = 450;
                var speed = 0.0008;

                var myC = 0;

                var myRadius2 = 541;
                var myColor = 0;
                var myColor2 = 0;

                var myNodes = $p.createJavaArray('Node', [nodeCount]);
                var myAttractor = null;



                function setup() {
                    offsetX = $p.width / 2;
                    offsetY = $p.height / 2;

                    $p.size(1920, 1080);
                    $p.colorMode($p.HSB, 100);
                    $p.background(255);

                    for (var i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++) {
                        myNodes[i] = new Node($p.width / 2, $p.height / 2);
                        myNodes[i].velocity.x = $p.random(-8, 8);
                        myNodes[i].velocity.y = $p.random(-8, 8);
                        myNodes[i].damping = 0.01;
                    }

                    myAttractor = new Attractor(0, 0);
                }
                $p.setup = setup;
                setup = setup.bind($p);



                function draw() {
                    var x = offsetX + $p.sin(angle * freqX + $p.radians(phi)) * $p.cos(angle * modFreqX) * 500;
                    var y = offsetY + $p.sin(angle * freqY) * $p.cos(angle * modFreqY) * 500;

                    angle += speed;

                    $p.fill(0, 10);
                    $p.rect(0, 0, $p.width, $p.height);

                    myAttractor.x = x;
                    myAttractor.y = y;

                    for (var i = 0; i < myNodes.length; i++) {
                        myAttractor.attract(myNodes[i]);
                        myNodes[i].damping = 0.01;

                        if (attOut == true) {
                            myAttractor.ramp = 0.7;
                            myAttractor.x = $p.width / 2;
                            myAttractor.y = $p.height / 2;

                            if (myNodes[i].myD >= myRadius2) {
                                myNodes[i].velocity.x = 0;
                                myNodes[i].velocity.y = 0;
                            }
                        } else {
                            myAttractor.ramp = 0.99;
                        }

                        if (myC > 100) myC = 0;

                        myC = myC + 0.000002;

                        myColor = $p.map($p.sin(myC), -0.98, 0.98, 0, 82);
                        myColor2 = $p.map($p.sin(myC), -0.98, 0.98, 20, 30);

                        myNodes[i].Update();
                        $p.noStroke();

                        if (rainbow == true) {
                            $p.fill(myColor, 100, 100);
                        } else {
                            $p.fill(myColor2, 100, 100);
                        }
                        $p.ellipse(myNodes[i].x, myNodes[i].y, 2.5, 2.5);
                    }

                    $p.noFill();
                    $p.stroke(40, 200, 100);
                    $p.ellipse($p.width / 2, $p.height / 2, 1080, 1080);
                    $p.noStroke();
                }
                $p.draw = draw;
                draw = draw.bind($p);


                function keyPressed() {
                    if ($p.key == (new $p.Character('1'))) {
                        attOut = false;
                        rainbow = false;
                        myAttractor.radius = 350;
                        myAttractor.strength = 0.4;
                        speed = 0.001;
                        console.log ('Pressed 1');
                    } else if ($p.key == (new $p.Character('2'))) {
                        attOut = false;
                        rainbow = true;
                        myAttractor.radius = 350;
                        myAttractor.strength = 0.7;
                        speed = 0.0008;
                        console.log ('Pressed 2');
                    } else if ($p.key == (new $p.Character('3'))) {
                        if (myAttractor.strength >= 0) myAttractor.strength *= -1;
                        attOut = true;
                        myAttractor.radius = 600;
                        console.log ('Pressed 3');
                    }
                }

                $p.keyPressed = keyPressed;
                keyPressed = keyPressed.bind($p);

            })

            var myCanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

            new Processing(myCanvas, mySketch);1
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="mycanvas">

    </canvas>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            console.log ('ready to go');
            whenImGoodAndReady ();
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone an idea?

Best regards

Comment: Can you provide a link to a page that this is running on?

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/8ym0xvcp/1/

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, Processing.js has its own sketch-level `x` and `y` variables. I'm not sure where they're defined- maybe in the canvas? (I'm not a JavaScript guy.)

You can prove this by running this small sketch in the Processing helper:

```
void draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(x, y, 25, 25);
}
```

This is causing you trouble because when you use `x` and `y` in your `Node` class, Processing.js thinks you're talking about the sketch-level `x` and `y` variables, not the `x` and `y` variables defined in the `PVector` class.

Then later when you try to use them to do your drawing, you **are** referring to the `PVector` `x` and `y`. But since you've never set them (you set the sketch-level `x` and `y`), they're still zero. You can prove this by drawing larger ellipses- they'll all be in the upper-left corner.

To fix this problem, you have to make sure that Processing.js knows which `x` and `y` variables you're talking about. One way to do that is by using the `super` keyword:

```
class Node extends PVector{
   public Node(float theX, float theY){
      super.x = theX
      super.y = theY;
   }
}
```

Similarly, you can call the super constructor directly:

```
class Node extends PVector{
   public Node(float theX, float theY){
      super(theX, theY);
   }
}
```

You could also just stop having your `Node` class extend `PVector`. You could then just define `x` and `y` variables in your `Node` class, or a `PVector position` variable.

Honestly, this is probably a better design anyway. A `Node` **has-a** `PVector`, not a `Node` **is-a** `PVector`. [Favor composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance), and [all that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).